# Maximum field width of scanf() with float

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf

The maximum field width specified in the control string in the `scanf()` function specifies the maximum number of characters that can be read into the variable.

According to this explanation, if the input for the following code is `123.456`, the output should be `123.45`, but I am getting `123.4` as the output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float f;
    scanf("%5f", &f);
    printf("%f", f);

    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to understand the reason for the output.

Comment: Isn't `123.4` five characters? Aren't you getting `123.400002` as the output?

Comment: Sindhuja, "but I am getting 123.4 as the output" --> best to post exact true output which is more like `"123.400001"` than `"123.4"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to this explanation,
> if the input for the following code is 123.456, the output should be 123.45 but I am getting 123.4 as the output.

Yes, you are getting the right output as per the code you have written.

The `"%5f"` you used in `scanf`, specifies the maximum number of characters to be read in the current reading operation.

so in your output, `123.4` are 5 characters( including the `.`)

If you want to print `x` number of digits after `.`, use `%.xf`

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    float f;
    printf("Enter a float number:");
    scanf("%f", &f);
    printf(" with .2f = %.2f\n", f);
    printf(" default  = %f\n", f);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Enter a float number:123.456
 with .2f = 123.46
 default  = 123.456001
```

Answer (score 0):

> The maximum field width specified in the control string in the scanf() function specifies the maximum number of characters that can be read into the variable.

Not quite.

With `scanf("%5f", &f);`, the `"%5f"` directs `scanf()` to first read and discard leading white-spaces.  These white-spaces do not count toward the 5.

Then up to 5 numeric characters are read.  These include `0-9, - +, e, E, NAN, nan, inf...`

```
  12345
 "123.45"     --> "123.4" is read, "5" remains in stdin
 "-123.45"    --> "-123." is read, "45" remains in stdin
 "+123.45"    --> "+123." is read, "45" remains in stdin
 "000123.45"  --> "00012" is read, "3.45" remains in stdin
 "1.2e34"     --> "1.2e3" is read, "4" remains in stdin
 "123x45"     --> "123" is read, "x45" remains in stdin
 " 123.45"    --> " 123.4" is read, "5" remains in stdin
```

Using a width limit with `"%f"` in `scanf()` can be problematic.  Consider setting aside `scanf()` and use `fgets()` to read user input into a *string* and then parse the string.

Comment: Oh, I'm a little new to C so I'm still figuring out the best input methods. I'll make sure to check out `fgets()`.